# Program adds random characters to string in C

Tags: arrays, string, getchar

I am in the process of learning C, and I stumbled upon a bug, and I can't seem to get my head around it.

This code is supposed to accept multiple lines of text (followed by an Enter), compare the lines to each other, stop comparing upon hitting EOF (aka. crtl - Z), choose the longest string and print it out to the console.

It does that, but upon printing the text out, it sometimes adds some additional characters to the output.

This is the code:

```
int get_line(char s[]);
void copy(char from[], char to[]);

main()
{
    int len;
    char line[1000];                       //the array which is used to compare
    char longest[1000];                    //the array in which the longest line will be stored
    int max = 1;                           //the maximum length of a line
    while ((len = get_line(line)) > 0)     //checks if the length of a line in more than 0
        if (len > max)
        {
            max = len;
            copy(line, longest);
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);             //prints out the longest line, if it exists
}

int get_line(char s[])
{
    int  c, i;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)     //reads the line until ^Z of Enter
        s[i] = c;
    return (i);
}

copy(char from[], char to[])
{
    for (int i = 0; from[i] != '\n'; ++i)
        to[i] = from [i];
}
```

Comment: Without having read your code, this almost always means you have failed to null-terminate a string somewhere.

Comment: Where in your code do you expect the `'\n'` to enter the array?

Comment: Yep, look at `get_line()`.

Comment: As far as I can understand C, I think that `'\n'` enters upon pressing Enter in the `getchar()` function.

Comment: When you say null-terminate it, you mean, to add a `\0` to the array? Why is that important? And thanks, that is probably the answer to my problem

Comment: Because the convention for strings in C is that they are null terminated.  In particular, when you pass an array to `printf()`, it will continue printing characters until it reaches `'\0'`, which is why it is printing characters you don't want.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much. :)

Comment: You have a similar issue in `copy`: it ought to stop upon reaching a terminating null, and be sure to null terminate the copy.  (Or rewrite to use the standard `strcpy()`.)  I must also point out that your code has a security vulnerability: if a line is more than 1000 characters long it will overflow your buffer.  I understand wanting to keep things simple as you get started, but it's also important to avoid forming bad habits.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but how could I stop the user from entering more that 1000 characters? Is it enough if I check the inputted text after the `getchar()` function, and if it has less than 999 characters to pass it over to the string?

Comment: `c = getchar()` will put `'\n'` in the local `char` variable `c`, but you never put a `'\n'` at the end of the array in `get_line`.

Answer (score 0):

In C a String is an Array of chars which is terminated with `\0`, this is called a [null terminated String](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/2530/spr17/Notes/C/String/nullterm.html).
So when calling `printf("%s",longest)`, it will print each element in the `longest[]` array which has length 1000.

To fix this you have to set the length of your char Array to the length of the actual String plus 1, and set `longest[length +1] = '\0'`.

This will tell the `printf()` function that the String ends at length + 1.